# Edit active WPF control in an active window

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, winforms-interop

I have a WPF window with a WindowsFormsHost object inside it. Ideally, I would like to access the WindowsForm control while the window is active.

I can register a name or anything like that I would need for the WindowsFormsHost control, and then do something along the lines of:

```
            WindowCollection mainWin = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows;
```

In this particular case I know the window I need will always be in mainWin[2], but I'm not sure how I can access the WindowsFormsHost object directly to add a Winform control to it.

Comment: Did you try giving the WindowsFormsHost a name and then, once you have a reference to the WindowsFormsHost, casing the Child property to the type it contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pseudo code, you will need a MyWindow class with a public property exposing the WindowsFormsHost Controll in this window with the name of MyWindowsFormsHost.

```
WindowCollection mainWin = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows;
MyWindow win = (MyWindow)mainWin[2];
win.MyWindowsFormsHost.Child = MyNewControl;
```

Comment: would this be roughly the same thing, except accessing the WindowsFormsHost directly?

                    WindowsFormsHost winTestt =     (WindowsFormsHost)mainWin[2].FindName("winformhost");
                


    winTestt.Child = this;

Comment: yeah, this should work if your control has the name winformhost.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want to acheive:

XAML

```
    <WindowsFormsHost Name="host"></WindowsFormsHost>
```

Code

```
private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var txb = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            host.Child = txb ;
            host.Child = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid();
        }
```